# How to create hyperlink after finding the words from text file

Tags: php, file-io, hyperlink

I have a text file containing links and the website names.

**For example:**

> Yahoo http://www.yahoo.com
>   Google http://www.google.com

then i have to load this text file into my php website. I can load the file

then I have to convert this texts into hyperlink. I have to find the links' position.

**I have used:**

```
echo strchr("$array[$x]","http") // find the hyperlink
echo substr("$array[$x]",0,8) // find the website name
```

After finding the websites' names and their hyperlinks
how can I use `<a href ...></a>` to create links?

**I tried:**

```
echo "<a href = "echo strchr("$array[$x]","http");>echo substr("$array[$x]",0,8). "<br>\n"; </a>
```

But it doesn't work. I don't know how to do it in fact.
Can anyone here help me to fix it?

---

**Here are my sample codes:**

> s13.postimg.org/ce8omobnr/image.png
>
> s23.postimg.org/ym3nifyfv/image.png

Comment: Please show a sample of your text file.

Comment: `@OP-MN Ho`. You should have posted your original sample codes from the beginning. The help that others provided, did not take into account that your samples no longer contain any spaces and you will be faced with a **surprise**. *Just saying*.

Comment: in the axample, whats are text or link?
link? [s13.postimg.org/ce8omobnr] text? [/image.png]
link? [s13.postimg.org/] text? [ce8omobnr/image.png]

Comment: im so sorry because when i tried to add images to my post, it was said that i did not have enough reputation to do so. so i need to upload the images from other websites

Comment: [s13.postimg.org/ce8omobnr/image.png]
this is the text file
...........

[s23.postimg.org/ym3nifyfv/image.png]
the second link is the codes appeared in my php website

Comment: @icc Ok, I'll edit your question. No problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you don't just use explode to split up the pieces of each line in the input file, unless the format of the input is different from what you showed.

Otherwise you can use file() to read in the input file, which returns an array of lines in the file. Then you can loop through this array and explode every line into two pieces. The first piece is the name, the second the hyperlink. Then just create the link tag and you're all set.

Example code:

```
<?php
$lines = file('input.txt');

foreach ($lines as $curLine)
{
    $pieces = explode(" ", $curLine, 2);

    echo sprintf("<a href=\"%s\">%s</a>\n", trim($pieces[1]), trim($pieces[0]));
}
```

**Edit:**
Just saw your update and noticed you have multiple spaces or other whitespace characters between the tokens on each line. In that case replace the line:

```
$pieces = explode(" ", $curLine, 2);
```

with:

```
$pieces = preg_split('/\s+/', $curLine);
```

**Edit 2:**
If the actual separator between the label and hyperlink on each line is one or multiple tabs and the labels may contain spaces (see Fred's comment below) then change the line into:

```
$pieces = preg_split('/\t+/', $curLine);
```

This will prevent the preg_split from splitting the labels containing spaces.

Comment: Your code works rather well, however the OP will run into problems if he/she happens to have a space anywhere. The OP changed his sample code from `Yahoo http://www.yahoo.com` to `s13.postimg.org/ce8omobnr/image.png`. Unless using `File2 s23.postimg.org/ym3nifyfv/image.png` instead of what he posted as sample `s23.postimg.org/ym3nifyfv/image.png`. *Just saying*.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I didn't see the edit in the question. Just updated my answer.

Comment: You're welcome. Now if I may add, and you don't have to go any further if you don't want to, but I must point out that another problem arises when using something to the affect of
`File 1 s13.postimg.org/ce8omobnr/image.png` with your update. Thought you might like to know, cheers.

Comment: Thanks again Fred. Could you explain that? It should work, because the pattern in my preg_split checks for 1 or more whitespace characters.

Comment: Would be happy to. Examples: **(not good)** => For instance, if the test.txt file contains `File 1 s13.postimg.org/ce8omobnr/image.png` it will produce `http://www.example.com/1%20s13.postimg.org/ce8omobnr/image.png`. - 

**(good)** => If it contains `File2 s23.postimg.org/ym3nifyfv/image.png` the link will be `http://www.example.com/s23.postimg.org/ym3nifyfv/image.png`. Notice `File 1` and `File2`. One has a space while the other doesn't.

Comment: Ah yeah I see what you mean. The OP should really specify those things though otherwise I can't provide him with an answer that fits all those possible scenarios. In case the labels can contain spaces and the actual separator between the label and the hyperlinks are tabs then he could simply change the preg_split pattern to '/\t+/'.

Comment: Wait, scratch that... brb.

Comment: If .txt file has in 2 lines: `File 1 s13.postimg.org/ce8omobnr/image.png` **=** `http://www.example.com/1` **and** `File2 s23.postimg.org/ym3nifyfv/image.png1` **=** `http://www.example.com/s23.postimg.org/ym3nifyfv/image.png`. If space between `File 1 and filename.png`, and space between `File2 and filename.png`. Yet no space in `File2` between `File` and `2`.

Comment: Yeah exactly, too many things for such a project. Unless the OP wants to hire a developper, now that's another story.

Comment: guys, did u see that "http://s13.postimg.org/ce8omobnr/image.png" is a link to a image? post it in your brouser..

Comment: I remember being faced with a similar problem myself some time back and did figure out how to do it, but it being almost 4:00 am here, my head's just not fit enough to go and find it. I'm sure it's in here *somewhere*. Good work though, cheers!

Comment: @Fred As long as the separator is consistent (best would be tabs) it wouldn't matter. But yeah, as long as the OP leaves us in the dark... ;)

Comment: @kraysak Yeah, I saw that and that's what I based my updated answer on. By the looks of it it's tabs separating the label and URL.

Comment: Key-riced... I didn't see the OP's comment about his image file just being "text". *groan* Ok, gotta edit his question again.

Comment: so so so sorry!!!
I m new to php. i just learnt php since yesterday but i have to hand in such project.. thats why i seek help here.
you guys have helped me a lot!!!!!!!!!
the answers you guys answered have already been sufficient enough to finish my project!!!

Comment: @Ruben He now has a choice then with the added pattern `'/\t+/'` you posted earlier. Let's hope he sees it. lol

Comment: @Fred Looks like he did. Mission accomplished. :)

Comment: @icc Great that it helped you out. Good luck with the project.

Comment: @Ruben The OP won't have to change anything. I just made a new `tab-delimited` file and it worked fine (didn't need the `'/\t+/'`). Just as long as he keeps both entities in single words, will be ok.

Comment: websites' names and the URL are separated by numbers of spaces... umm.. it doesnt need to be tabs .. i just separated them in tabs in the text file..

Comment: @Ruben Indeed, `Mission Accomplished`. **Bravo** ;-)

Comment: yes i have accepted his answer 
umm sorry  how can i +1 on your part?

Comment: @icc Okay, but that's important to know. So here's what the possible scenarios are: 1. You don't use spaces in the labels (first column in your text file). In that scenario you can use the preg_split('/\s+/', $curLine); code. 2. You DO use spaces in the labels. In that case the question is if there's always at least two spaces between the label and the URL. If yes then change the preg_split into preg_split('/\s{2,}/', $curLine); If no then the parsing will be a bit more complicated, but I won't go into that until I know for sure.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $file1 = "test.txt";
    $lines = file($file1);
    foreach($lines as $line_num => $line)
    {
    //echo $line;
    $piece=explode(' ',$line);
    //echo $piece[0]."<br>";
    //echo $piece[1];
    echo '<a href="'.$piece[1].'">'.$piece[0].'</a><br>';
    }
```

the file "test.txt":

```
Yahoo http://www.yahoo.com
Google http://www.google.com
```

EDIT

so, a litle update:

```
$file1 = "updir/bookmark.txt";
$lines = file($file1);
foreach($lines as $line)
{
    $piece=explode(" ",$line);
    $link=trim($piece[1]);
    $text=trim($piece[0]);
    echo '<a href="'.$link.'">'.$text.'</a><br>';
}
```

Comment: You forgot your closing `}` after `echo '<a href="'.$piece[1].'">'.$piece[0].'</a><br>';`.

Comment: See my comment in the other answer provided by `Ruben`. The OP will run into the same problem. You should add some notes to that affect.